# Ruby hash path to each leaf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, tree

First of all I beg your pardon if this question already exists, I deeply searched for a solution here but I've been able to find it, nevertheless I feel it's a problem so common that is seems so strange to not find anything here...

My struggle is the following: given an hash, I need to return all the PATHS to each leaf as an array of strings; so, for example:

- `{:a=> 1}` gives `['a']`
- `{:a=>{:b=>3, :c=>4}` returns an array with **two** results: `["a.b", "a.c"]`
- `{:a=>[1, {:b=>2}]}` will result in `["a.0", "a.1.b"]`
  and so on...

I have found only partial solutions to this and with dozens of codelines. like this

```
def pathify
  self.keys.inject([]) do |acc, element|
    return acc if element.blank?

    if !(element.is_a?(Hash) || element.is_a?(Array))
      if acc.last.is_a?(Array)
        acc[acc.size-1] = acc.last.join('.')
      else
        acc << element.to_s
      end
    end

    if element.is_a?(Hash)
      element.keys.each do |key|
        if acc.last.is_a?(Array)
          acc.last << key.to_s
        else
          acc << [key.to_s]
        end
        element[key].pathify
      end
    end

    if element.is_a?(Array)
      acc << element.map(&:pathify)
    end
    acc
  end
end
```

But it does not work in all cases and is extremely inefficient. Summarizing: is there any way to "pathify" an hash to return all the paths to each leaf in form of array of strings?
Thank you for the help!

**Edited**
Adding some specs

```
for {} it returns []
for {:a=>1} it returns ["a"]
for {:a=>1, :b=>1} it returns ["a", "b"]
for {:a=>{:b=>1}} it returns ["a.b"] (FAILED - 1) got: ["a"]
for {:a=>{:b=>1, :c=>2}} it returns ["a.b", "a.c"] (FAILED - 2) got: ["a"]
for {:a=>[1]} it returns ["a.0"] (FAILED - 3) got: ["a"]
for {:a=>[1, "b"]} it returns ["a.0", "a.1"] (FAILED - 4) got: ["a"]
```

Comment: Which case does it not work for, and by what benchmark do you claim it's inefficient? My suspicion is that in truth, your complaint is just that the above code looks "complex", and you'd like a shorter solution.

Comment: Good point. let me add some specs to show when it fails

Comment: Also: How do you expect to distinguish between `{'a' => { '1' => 'b'}}` and `{'a' => ['b']}`? Both keys would be represented by `a.1`. Maybe that's not a problem if you expect hash keys to be symbols, not strings, or for such a scenario to otherwise simply not occur.

Comment: good question too. Let's assume that keys will never be integers. only strings/symbols so 1 will be always be the second element of an array. There are no dates nor special chars. just `[a-Z-_]`

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to https://github.com/wteuber/yaml_normalizer/blob/b85dca7357df00757c471acb5dadb79a53dd27c1/lib/yaml_normalizer/ext/namespaced.rb

So I tweaked the code a bit to fit your needs:

```rb
module Leafs
  def leafs(namespace = [], tree = {})
    each do |key, value|
      child_ns = namespace.dup << key
      if value.instance_of?(Hash)
        value.extend(Leafs).leafs child_ns, tree
      elsif value.instance_of?(Array)
        value.each.with_index.inject({}) {|h, (v,k)| h[k]=v; h}.extend(Leafs).leafs child_ns, tree
      else
        tree[child_ns.join('.')] = value
      end
    end
    tree.keys.to_a
  end
end
```

Here is how to use it:

```rb
h = {a: [1, "b"], c: {d:1}}
h.extend(Leafs)
h.leafs
# => ["a.0", "a.1", "c.d"]
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```rb
def show(key, path)
  if path.is_a? Array
    path.map {|p| "#{key}.#{p}"}
  else
    path == "" ? key.to_s : "#{key}.#{path}"
  end
end

def pathify(input)
  if input.is_a? Hash
    input.map do |k,v|
      sub_path = pathify(v)
      show(k, sub_path)
    end.flatten
  elsif input.is_a? Array
    input.map.with_index do |v, i|
      sub_path = pathify(v)
      show(i, sub_path)
    end.flatten
  else
    ""
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def leaf_paths(enum)
  return unless [Hash, Array].include? enum.class

  [].tap do |result|
    if enum.is_a?(Hash)
      enum.each { |k, v| result = attach_leaf_paths(k, v, result) }
    elsif enum.is_a?(Array)
      enum.each_with_index { |elem, index| result = attach_leaf_paths(index, elem, result) }
    end
  end
end

def attach_leaf_paths(key, value, result)
  if (children = leaf_paths(value))
    children.each { |child| result << "#{key}.#{child}" }
  else
    result << key.to_s
  end
  result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def pathify(what)
    paths = []
    if what.is_a?(Array)
        what.each_with_index do | element, index |
            paths+= pathify(element).map{|e| index.to_s + '.' + e.to_s}
        end
    elsif what.is_a?(Hash)
        what.each do |k,v|
            paths+= pathify(v).map{|e| k.to_s + '.' + e.to_s}
        end
    else
        paths.append('')
    end
    paths.map{|e| e.delete_suffix('.')}
end
```